# Ruby Beginner- unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am SUPER new to ruby, and I am trying to following instructions on how to build a rectangle. I am following along as carefully as possible, I triple checked I typed it correctly. I even retyped it. The problem seems to be in the end. My terminal keeps giving me the error: *shapes.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end*

Can anyone help me? I think it might be an issue with the 1.upto, but i'm not sure. Thank you so much!!

```
    puts "Welcome to Shapes"
    print "How big do you want your shape? "
    shape_size = gets
    shape_size = shape_size.chomp
    print "Outside letter: "
    outside_letter = gets
    outside_letter = outside_letter.chomp
    print " Inside Letter: "
    inside_letter = gets
    inside_letter = inside_letter.chomp
    puts "About to draw a shape #{shape_size} big"
    puts "using #{outside_letter} for the edge"
    puts "and #{inside_letter} for the inside"
    width = shape_size
    height=shape_size
    1.upto(height) do |row|
    if row==1
        puts outside_letter * width
    elsif row==height
        puts outside_letter * width
    else
        middle= inside_letter * (width-2)
    puts
        "#{outside_letter}#{middle}#{outside_letter}"
    end
```

Comment: You are missing an `end` for `do`

Comment: One of the first things you'll have to pay very close attention to when programming is *indentation*. Here you can't see a problem because you haven't indented blocks correctly.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. We don't care if you're new, we expect you to research, put a lot of effort into solving the problem, then ask a well thought-out question. See "[ask]" which also links to the above link. If you're having a problem with your code, then, in addition, read "[mcve]". If you keep your code indented it'll be easier to see if there are problems with missing block ends or `}` and won't ask questions that are caused by a syntax error.

Comment: Tin Man, please don't be rude. I'm following along in a book, and that's how it's shown. I don't know anyone else as of yet that does this, so I went to a forum. If you don't care to take the time to answer my question or are angry because of the question asked, don't answer it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @brianslattery thank you for taking the time to explain a few things. I appreciate it!

Comment: Nobody is being rude. We have published expectations and standards and we'd like you to work to those. SO isn't a "help me only" site, it's a "let's help the world" site, where you are asking programming questions nobody has asked before. To do that requires effort on your part to ask a good question and then we help provide the answers. I'd recommend reading all the links mentioned above as they'll help you as you contribute.

Comment: +1 Welcome to ruby, Danyon! Glad to have you. Don't get discouraged by StackOverflow's high standards; they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need one more `end`:

```
puts "Welcome to Shapes"
print "How big do you want your shape? "
shape_size = gets
shape_size = shape_size.chomp
print "Outside letter: "
outside_letter = gets
outside_letter = outside_letter.chomp
print " Inside Letter: "
inside_letter = gets
inside_letter = inside_letter.chomp
puts "About to draw a shape #{shape_size} big"
puts "using #{outside_letter} for the edge"
puts "and #{inside_letter} for the inside"
width = shape_size
height=shape_size
1.upto(height) do |row|
  if row==1
    puts outside_letter * width
  elsif row==height
    puts outside_letter * width
  else
    middle= inside_letter * (width-2)
    puts
    "#{outside_letter}#{middle}#{outside_letter}"
  end
end # <--- here
```

Since you are learning here, I felt compelled to add more detail:

When you have a block, such as the `1.upto(height) do |row|` in your code, that will always require an `end`, as it is a block (think of it like a unit of code). Within that block, you are executing the code for each item within the enumerable (ex. array). In this case, your enumerable is an array of each whole number between 1 and the value of `height`:

```
2.3.0 :005 > 1.upto(4) do |number|
2.3.0 :006 >     puts "The number is: #{number}"
2.3.0 :007?>   end
The number is: 1
The number is: 2
The number is: 3
The number is: 4
```

Comment: Please avoid inserting "Edit" or "Update". We have a revision history we can check if we need to see when something changed, that also shows us what changed. Instead add the change where it would have been originally. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/153968 explains it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Fix Indenting
To fix this, first fix your indenting. This will usually make it obvious where the end is missing. You can see where your indenting is off by using the warning flag when running your ruby program: e.g. ruby -w my_program.rb.

Step 2: Decipher the warning
Look at the line numbers the warnings point to. From these, you may be able to figure out where your end is missing. If not, go to the next step.

Step 3: Isolate Code Causing Error
If you're not able to figure out where the issue is due to the warnings, try commenting out chunks of code and seeing if you can get your program to run. Then uncomment and run your code chunk by chunk until the error returns. Using this method you'll be able to isolate where your end is missing.