# Ruby returns "unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" error

Tags: ruby, math, calculator

So I made a calculator on ruby but it says:

> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

I want the code like mine or so.

```
class String
  def green; "\e[32m#{self}\e[0m" end
end
def load
require 'progress_bar'
bar = ProgressBar.new

100.times do
  sleep 0.1
  bar.increment!
end
load
def start
system("msfdb stop")
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[|]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[/]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[-]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[\]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "[+] SCRIPT GESTARTET".green 
sleep 2
system("clear")
puts "#####################################################################################################################################################################################".green
sleep 1
puts "#LINZENZ VON Qerim Iseni09                                                                                                                                                          #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Bitte Verkauf es nicht                                                                                                                                                             #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Bitte modifiziere es nicht                                                                                                                                                         #".green
sleep 1
puts "#ändere es nicht                                                                                                                                                                    #".green
sleep 1
puts "#usw.                                                                                                                                                                               #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Danke dass du es installiert hast.                                                                                                                                                 #".green
sleep 1
puts "#   ###########       ##########    #######      #######            #                #                                                                                              #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #              # #              # #                                                                                             #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #             #   #            #   #                                                                                            #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #            #     #          #     #                                                                                           #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #        #  #      ##########    #######         #           #       #        #       #                                                                                          #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #         # #      #             ##              #          #         #      #         #                                                                                         #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #          ##      #             # #             #         #           #    #           #                                                                                        #".green
sleep 1
puts "#   ############      #             #   #           #        #             #  #             #                                                                                       #".green
sleep 1
puts "#               #     ##########    #     #      #######    #               ##               #                                                                                      #".green
sleep 1
puts "#####################################################################################################################################################################################".green
sleep 5
system("clear")
system("msfdb start")
sleep 5
end
start
loop do
load
system("clear")
def danke_function
    sleep 2
    puts "DANKE FUER BENUTZEN!".green
    puts "Programmiert von Qerim Iseni09".green
    sleep 5
    system("clear")
end

def easter_function
 loop do
    puts "DU HAST DEN EASTEREGG GEFUNDEN!".green
 end
end

def addition_function
      puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
      n1 = gets.to_i
      n2 = gets.to_i
      puts "Rechne aus…".green
      sleep 2
      puts "Resultat ist #{n1 + n2}".green
      danke_function
end

def subtraction_function
    puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus…".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 - n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def multiplication_function
    puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus…".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 * n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def division_function
puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus…".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 / n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def index
puts "Willst du */+- Rechnen?".green
response = gets.chomp
if response == "+" then
   addition_function
end
if response == "-" then
   subtraction_function
end
if response == "*" then
   multiplication_function
end
if response == "/" then
   division_function
end
if response == "S" then
   easter_function
end
if response == "exit" then
   danke_function
   exit
end
if response == "qerim" then
   puts "Qerim Wie Gehts?"
   re = gets.chomp
   puts "Also #{re}"
   index
end

if response == "exit!" then
    system("clear")
    exit
end
if response == "execute" then
   re2 = gets.chomp
system("#{re2}")
end
end
index
end
```

thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's your first post, so no need to feel bad, but you'll need to improve the quality of your question to get a good response. Check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, you'll want to: (1) Write a title that asks a specific, focused technical question, (2) proofread your question so that it's clear for other readers, (3) explain what work you've done to troubleshoot the issue independently so far.

Comment: Also, this is a common beginner mistake for new Rubyists, so you might be able to find some good tips from people with similar issues if you search around a bit. For example, if you google the error message, have you looked at similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621770/ruby-beginner-unexpected-end-of-input-expecting-keyword-end)? For your code, have you checked how the `def`/`end` and `do`/`end` pairs match up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a couple of changes to the code. seems like some compilers cant reach the German characters. I tried running using an online compiler and it was showing errors in the statements with these characters "..." and others too.

```
class String
      def green; "\e[32m#{self}\e[0m" end
    end
def load
require 'progress_bar'
bar = ProgressBar.new

100.times do
  sleep 0.1
  bar.increment!
end
load
def start
system("msfdb stop")
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[|]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[/]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[-]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "STARTE SCRIPT[\]".green
sleep 1
system("clear")
puts "[+] SCRIPT GESTARTET".green 
sleep 2
system("clear")
puts "#####################################################################################################################################################################################".green
sleep 1
puts "#LINZENZ VON Qerim Iseni09                                                                                                                                                          #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Bitte Verkauf es nicht                                                                                                                                                             #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Bitte modifiziere es nicht                                                                                                                                                         #".green
sleep 1
puts "#andere es nicht                                                                                                                                                                    #".green
sleep 1
puts "#usw.                                                                                                                                                                               #".green
sleep 1
puts "#Danke dass du es installiert hast.                                                                                                                                                 #".green
sleep 1
puts "#   ###########       ##########    #######      #######            #                #                                                                                              #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #              # #              # #                                                                                             #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #             #   #            #   #                                                                                            #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #           #      #             #      #        #            #     #          #     #                                                                                           #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #        #  #      ##########    #######         #           #       #        #       #                                                                                          #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #         # #      #             ##              #          #         #      #         #                                                                                         #".green
sleep 1
puts "#  #          ##      #             # #             #         #           #    #           #                                                                                        #".green
sleep 1
puts "#   ############      #             #   #           #        #             #  #             #                                                                                       #".green
sleep 1
puts "#               #     ##########    #     #      #######    #               ##               #                                                                                      #".green
sleep 1
puts "#####################################################################################################################################################################################".green
sleep 5
system("clear")
system("msfdb start")
sleep 5
end
start
loop do
load
system("clear")
def danke_function
    sleep 2
    puts "DANKE FUER BENUTZEN!".green
    puts "Programmiert von Qerim Iseni09".green
    sleep 5
    system("clear")
end

def easter_function
 loop do
    puts "DU HAST DEN EASTEREGG GEFUNDEN!".green
 end
end

def addition_function
      puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
      n1 = gets.to_i
      n2 = gets.to_i
      puts "Rechne aus".green
      sleep 2
      puts "Resultat ist #{n1 + n2}".green
      danke_function
end

def subtraction_function
    puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 - n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def multiplication_function
    puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 * n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def division_function
puts "Welche Nummern willst du ausrechnen?".green
    n1 = gets.to_i
    n2 = gets.to_i
    puts "Rechne aus".green
    sleep 2
    puts "Resultat ist #{n1 / n2}".green
    danke_function
end

def index
puts "Willst du */+- Rechnen?".green
response = gets.chomp
if response == "+" then
   addition_function
end
if response == "-" then
   subtraction_function
end
if response == "*" then
   multiplication_function
end
if response == "/" then
   division_function
end
if response == "S" then
   easter_function
end
if response == "exit" then
   danke_function
   exit
end
if response == "qerim" then
   puts "Qerim Wie Gehts?"
   re = gets.chomp
   puts "Also #{re}"
   index
end

if response == "exit!" then
    system("clear")
    exit
end
if response == "execute" then
   re2 = gets.chomp
system("#{re2}")
end
end
index
end
end
```

Comment: You're right Crisphine my Problem was that i forget to install the Progressbar. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your calculator seems to work just fine - I simply copied your code into a local file and added the ProgressBar class myself - then I ran the ruby script.

Not sure how we can help if there isn't a problem.